# Is there any way to create a database on Hive using Python?

Tags: python, hive, bigdata, pyhive

I want to automate the whole process to test a scenario where I would like to create a database, perform an operation and then delete the database. Is there any way to do it using Python 3. I tried with PyHive, but it requires the database name to connect to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one cannot connect to database and need to run hive commands from terminal, we can use Popen function from subprocess module to use Hive from the Terminal.

```
        if self.is_database_exist():
            print("Exists")
            self.drop_hive_database()
        else:
            print("Not Exists")
        put = Popen(["hive", "-S", "-e", "create database {0};".format(self.database)], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, bufsize=-1)
        out, exp = put.communicate()
        if "failed" in str(out).lower():
            self.logger("Failed to create Hive Database %s!" % self.database)
            raise Exception("Failed to create database")
```

Here self.database contains Name of the database, and is database exist function is checking if the database already exists, then we are dropping the database and recreating it.